# Flash SWF Banner rotating issue

Tags: javascript, html, flash, banner

I am having problems with my code in letting my three SWF banners to rotate through, currently it just shows one banner on each page refresh where as I want it to go through all three SWF banners one after the other on the page.

Current code below:

```
<script language="javascript">

files = new Array();

files[0] = "https://f88a4ec1239322f1b0543150463705209caf87a8.googledrive.com/host/0BzJtTNkbexMAcU9STWNpU2dQX1E/CS_0814_VG_Sky.swf";

files[1] = "https://f88a4ec1239322f1b0543150463705209caf87a8.googledrive.com/host/0BzJtTNkbexMAcU9STWNpU2dQX1E/NMM_SCS_0814_VG_Sky.swf";

files[2] = "https://f88a4ec1239322f1b0543150463705209caf87a8.googledrive.com/host/0BzJtTNkbexMAcU9STWNpU2dQX1E/QH_tea_banner_v5.swf";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length);

movie = files[index];


document.write('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width=225 height=600>');


document.write('<param name=movie value="' + movie + '"> <param name=quality value=high> <param name=bgcolor value=#ffffff> <param name="menu" value="false">');


document.write('<embed src="' + movie + '" quality=high  menu=false width=225 height=600 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed>');
document.write('</object>');

</script>
```

Any help would be great, thank you!